# Access violation error in ace log_msg.cpp library file for writing debug logs

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, access-violation, corba, ace

I have a project that use CORBA/ACE for connection between two distributed module and when I transfered my solution from MSVS2008 to MSVS2015 I faced with access violation error in every use of **ACE_DEBUG** function for write logs of project and when I followed code I find that the null pointer error is before this part of code:

```
if (tracing)
    this->start_tracing ();
```

this is in Log_Msg.cpp that is a file of ace library. Here is the fuction that error generates in it:

```
    ssize_t
ACE_Log_Msg::log (ACE_Log_Record &log_record,
                  int suppress_stderr)
{
  ssize_t result = 0;

  // Format the message and print it to stderr and/or ship it off to
  // the log_client daemon, and/or print it to the ostream.  Of
  // course, only print the message if "SILENT" mode is disabled.
  if (ACE_BIT_DISABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_,
                        ACE_Log_Msg::SILENT))
    {
      bool tracing = this->tracing_enabled ();
      this->stop_tracing ();

#if !defined (ACE_WIN32)
      // Make this block signal-safe.
      ACE_Log_Msg_Sig_Guard sb;
#endif /* !ACE_WIN32 */

      // Do the callback, if needed, before acquiring the lock
      // to avoid holding the lock during the callback so we don't
      // have deadlock if the callback uses the logger.
      if (ACE_BIT_ENABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_,
                           ACE_Log_Msg::MSG_CALLBACK)
          && this->msg_callback () != 0)
        this->msg_callback ()->log (log_record);

      // Make sure that the lock is held during all this.
      ACE_MT (ACE_GUARD_RETURN (ACE_Recursive_Thread_Mutex, ace_mon,
                                *ACE_Log_Msg_Manager::get_lock (),
                                -1));

      if (ACE_BIT_ENABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_,
                           ACE_Log_Msg::STDERR)
          && !suppress_stderr) // This is taken care of by our caller.
        log_record.print (ACE_Log_Msg::local_host_,
                          ACE_Log_Msg::flags_,
                          stderr);

      if (ACE_BIT_ENABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_, ACE_Log_Msg::CUSTOM) ||
          ACE_BIT_ENABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_, ACE_Log_Msg::SYSLOG) ||
          ACE_BIT_ENABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_, ACE_Log_Msg::LOGGER))
        {
          // Be sure that there is a message_queue_, with multiple threads.
          ACE_MT (ACE_Log_Msg_Manager::init_backend ());
        }


      if (ACE_BIT_ENABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_, ACE_Log_Msg::LOGGER) ||
          ACE_BIT_ENABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_, ACE_Log_Msg::SYSLOG))
        {
          result =
            ACE_Log_Msg_Manager::log_backend_->log (log_record);
        }

      if (ACE_BIT_ENABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_, ACE_Log_Msg::CUSTOM) &&
          ACE_Log_Msg_Manager::custom_backend_ != 0)
        {
          result =
            ACE_Log_Msg_Manager::custom_backend_->log (log_record);
        }

      // This must come last, after the other two print operations
      // (see the <ACE_Log_Record::print> method for details).
      if (ACE_BIT_ENABLED (ACE_Log_Msg::flags_,
                           ACE_Log_Msg::OSTREAM)
          && this->msg_ostream () != 0)
        log_record.print (ACE_Log_Msg::local_host_,
                          ACE_Log_Msg::flags_,
#if defined (ACE_LACKS_IOSTREAM_TOTALLY)
                          static_cast<FILE *> (this->msg_ostream ())
#else  /* ! ACE_LACKS_IOSTREAM_TOTALLY */
                          *this->msg_ostream ()
#endif /* ! ACE_LACKS_IOSTREAM_TOTALLY */
                          );

      if (tracing)
        this->start_tracing ();
   }

  return result;
}
```

I used __try/__except and other exception handlers but I can't solve it. I don't have such error in MSVS2008. maybe I should set some setting or add new file but I don't know what it is.

Please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You explicitly have to initialize the ACE library. When you have a regular main() we have some macros doing that. Probably you have some special main, try to call `ACE::init();` at the start of that and `ACE::fini();` at the end. See `ACE_wrappers/tests/ACE_Init_Test.cpp`.

Also you have to compile ACE/TAO with the Visual Studio 2015 compiler. Maybe upgrade directly to Visual Studio 2017, that compiler is supported by ACE/TAO 6.4.3/2.4.3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but ACE::init() already added to initialization part of project I also test to add it in other places that was for initialization but there is the same problem yet. Is it necessary to add ACE::init() to some other parts?

Comment: I said in my question that we don't have such an error for MSVS2008 and since we transfered project to 2015 the problem started!!!

Comment: Have you recompiled ACE/TAO using msvc2015?

Comment: If you talk about solutions that are in ace wrapper folder,NO! Which solutions should I recompile ?

Comment: You should compile also ACE/TAO with msvc2015. What you need to compile depends on what you need of ACE/TAO. Maybe use the same solution (but then for msvc2015) and compile that?

Comment: I don't know a lot because I didn't compile it before. there is two solution ace and tao. can I download new version of ace/tao and use it instead of this old version?it there a tutorial for compile ace/tao?

Comment: Probably the TAO/TAO_ACE solution is the best. Probably compiles way too much and with MPC you could generate what you need. Maybe check the CORBA Programmers Guide which you can download for free from http://www.remedy.nl. That has some information about how to compile TAO.

Comment: Excuse me for my endless questions. but I tried to build TAO_ACE_vc_14 and after building some of projects in solution when try to invoke files like:


33>  Invoking "..\..\..\bin\tao_idl on IdUniquenessPolicy.pidl"
33>  Invoking "..\..\..\bin\tao_idl on ImplicitActivationPolicy.pidl" 
...
an error messagebox appear and said tad_idl.exe stopped working.what is this? what should I do with this error?

Comment: You have to add %ACE_ROOT%\lib to your path

Comment: I compiled almost all main solutions of ace_wrapper except tao/tao because that was very huge and. then I tried to compile my project with this new ace_wrapper but there are many errors:
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int assert.h-----Error C2086 'int ACE_END_VERSIONED_NAMESPACE_DECL': redefinition crtdbg.h and many other errors. unfortunately there is not other good resource that i can use it for my problems and you are only one that can help me :(

Comment: You probably haven't created the ace/config.h file, see the documentation or your old tree